# how to dismiss request from contractor in flutter when using final

Tags: flutter, dart

class Reusable extends StatelessWidget {
const Reusable({
Key? key,
required this.color,
this.cardchild,
}) : super(key: key);

final Color color;
final Widget cardchild;

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
final Color? color; 
final Widget? cardchild;
```